# Sorting csv file by 5th column using bash

Tags: linux, bash

The file looks like

```
5.1,3.5,1.4,0.2,Banana
4.9,3.0,1.4,0.6,Apple
4.8,2.8,1.3,1.2,Apple
```

and I need to have it be

```
4.9,3.0,1.4,0.2,Apple
4.8,2.8,1.3,1.2,Apple
5.1,3.5,1.4,0.2,Banana
```

I have been trying to use

```
sort -t, -k5 file.csv > sorted.csv
```

All it does is make it

```
5.1,3.5,1.4,0.2,Banana
4.8,2.8,1.3,1.2,Apple
4.9,3.0,1.4,0.6,Apple
```

How do I make it like this? It does not seem to be sorting it at all.

Comment: Can't reproduce. Your command works fine over here

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about bash and belongs on [unix.se].

Comment: Same here. Sorts just fine for me.

Comment: @ColeJohnson Bash is on topic on SO. Just have a look at the [Bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bash) tag

Comment: @user000001 I am very aware it is. I'm suggesting that it may be better over there.

Comment: @mrm9084 Cannot reproduce either. Have you tried to delete all columns and perform sorting only for Banana and Apple? Did it work?

Comment: If you just cat the input csv what do you get? Are there any nonprinting characters in your input file? Try the command with the `-i` flag.

Answer (score 7):

GNU sort is locale sensitive, which can cause weirdness. Try the following and see if it makes a difference:

```
LC_ALL=C sort -t, -k5 file.csv > sorted.csv
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon.  You're correct that occasionally (or even always if your locale is set to something like `en_US.UTF-8`, as mine is), the locale can certainly affect the sort order of some data.  However, it is hard to see how the locale could affect this — indeed, it is hard to duplicate the problem, let alone sort it out (pun half-intended).

Comment: This was precisely what I needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Is this what you need to have it be

```
# sort -t . -nrk2 sorted.csv 
4.9,3.0,1.4,0.6,Apple
4.8,2.8,1.3,1.2,Apple
5.1,3.5,1.4,0.2,Banana
```