# Manipulating several files at once in R

Tags: r

I have several files in .txt format that I want to import into R, sort the rows them based on a variable and export only the first 50000 rows to a new file.
I have tried as below, but it never finishes and doesnt say that it is wrong. Any help please? Thanks.

```
 Map(function(x, y) {
+             all_content = readLines(x)
+             skip_second = all_content[-c(1:9)]
+             df <- read.table(textConnection(skip_second), header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
+             df1 = df[order(df$pvalue),]
+             df2 = df1[1:50000, c(1:3,12)]
+             write.table(df2,row.names=FALSE, quote=FALSE, file = y)
+     }, x = myfiles, y = newfiles)
```

Comment: this question is too vague.  It's not working could mean anything from 'it melted my apartment' to 'it mysteriously didn't automatically write my thesis'.  Please be more specific.

Comment: Thanks Alex. R doesn't show if there is an error, but doesn't finish to run as well. The file dimension is 600000 X 15 and it has taken more than 2 hours. It must have an error.

Comment: In the line `df[order(df$p-value),]`, you did not define what `value` is or why you would subtract a value from a numeric index that doesn't accept negative values.

Comment: @PierreLafortune p-value is the variable name. I have changed it as well as I thought it could be a problem, but it doesn't work as well.

Comment: Test it with some smaller files first.  Read.table has arguments to skip lines and terminate after a line count, may be faster than loading all that text into memory first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a duplicate, but the best answer is here: [Sorting csv file by 5th column using bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18642188/sorting-csv-file-by-5th-column-using-bash)

Use cat to combine the files and then pipe them to sort and pass the arguments as explained to sort on a particular field (you need to know the column number rather than the name). This will complete orders of magnitude faster than trying to do it in-memory in R.

If you're using Windows, I'm sorry but I don't know the equivalent PowerShell utility.